# Is it possible to adopt the interpretivism philosophy of science when conducting a deductive study?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

The philosophy of interpretivism is often associated with inductive studies. Is it considered too huge of a mismatch to adopt this philosophy for a qualitative deductive study? If so, what are the biggest implications?

Comment: As a philosopher of science, I'm having a hard time understanding what you are referring to. Can to add some references to sources or definitions of the terms you're using? I don't think "interpretivism" is a standard term.